# How to introduce users to a new buying process?

Tags: user-expectation, feedback

We created a B2B marketplace to let merchants and retailers trade their goods in a particular market. The buying process is similar to eBay: you can bid to an offer or instead buy specific amounts for a fixed price. The problem is that the merchant who created the offer has to accept it, so the user needs specific feedback when creating a proposal to buy something.

What is the best way to explain or give feedback on this process, so the user will not be confused when actually buying something while still having to wait for the confirmation?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Inline editing vs Edit view](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/28210/inline-editing-vs-edit-view)

Comment: Are you asking what the design for the buyer should look like, to make it clear whether he buys fixed-price (immediate payment, finally decided) vs. he bids and someone else may bid more (payment may be required later, decision on sale not yet taken)? If so, why don't you model your design after eBay? In other words, what is the best design you can come up with, and what specifically are you worried about it?

Comment: Link to a short explanatory video.

Comment: I recommend you to use some new feature onboarding techniques. This is a great article about onboarding: https://www.toptal.com/designers/product-design/guide-to-onboarding-ux

Answer (score 1):

When a user clicked the button, a notification bubble with a clarification can be shown, saying something like:

> You're order has been placed, the purchase will complete once accepted by the merchant.

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing more about your website, it is hard to give you a system-wide recommendation. However, you can start by making clear in the interface that the website does not behave like normal e-commerce.

For example, you could play with wording:

1. Instead of "Place Order", label the CTA as "Submit Proposal". And follow it up by, like @Pavel mentioned, some sort of confirmation confirming the proposal was submitted and a second notification will be sent when it is accepted.
2. Make sure there are multiple places in the website with simple graphics explaining how the buying process works and why. (Few people have patience to watch a video).
3. Possibly introduce order statuses. For example: Submitted, Accepted.